# Fragments y SQLiteDatabase

Tags: sqlite, android-fragment

Tengo un `fragments` realizado con **android studio** (el que viene por defecto Navigation Drawer). También tengo una `sql` en una clase llamada `DBHelper`. El código del fragmentes esta bien (por defecto), pero cuando quiero referenciar a la clase `DBHelper` como en este código el `this` del  `FSDbHelper dbdivlectura = new FSDbHelper(this);` me sale un error.

¿Como lo puedo quitar o que hay que hacer para poder manejar la clase de `sqlitel` en un `fragmenst`?

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_divisiones, container, false);
//  answerText = (View) vista.findViewById(R.id.act);
//  answerText.setText("Cambiado");


    FSDbHelper dbdivlectura = new FSDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase databasedias = dbdivlectura.getReadableDatabase();



    return vista;
}
```